Were there any significant differences in the responsibilities or authority of Annas and Caiaphas as high priest?
Luke writes that Annas and Caiaphas were high priests.

In Luke 3:2, while Annas and Caiaphas were high priests, the word of
God came to John the son of Zacharias in the wilderness.

Here Annas is stated as the high priest.

In Acts 4:6-7, as well as Annas the high priest, Caiaphas, John, and
Alexander, and as many as were of the family of the high priest, were
gathered together at Jerusalem. And when they had set them in the
midst, they asked, “By what power or by what name have you done
this?”

Caiaphas was the high priest who plotted to kill Jesus.

In Matthew 26:3-4, Then the chief priests, the scribes, and the elders
of the people assembled at the palace of the high priest, who was
called Caiaphas, and plotted to take Jesus by trickery and kill
Him.

Was there more than one high priest at the a same time?
What were the differences in their responsibilities and authority?

Annas was high priest for 10 years, and Caiaphas, his son-in-law was the current high priest. Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annas. (wikipedia is not a reliable source, but sometimes, it works as a source).

Luke is writing with the Law in mind. Annas should have high priest for life. Caiaphas, as a son-in-law had no legal right to serve as the high priest.

Between Josephus, the New Testament, and the Rabbis, you get this paradigm where Annas maintains a highly dignified and influential position long after his tenure as high priest is complete. If he isn't the high priest somehow one of his children are and he's seemingly "puppeteering" them on influential decisions. While Caiaphas ends up holding the high priesthood the longest, I think its telling that it's always "Annas and Caiaphas" in the Gospels. In John's gospel, it is apparently more impactful to only preserve a story of Jesus presentation before Annas, not Caiaphas. Then in Acts, Peter and John are presented before Annas and his four sons, Jonathan is among them and is either the high priest at the time or about to be.
A good way to think about Annas rule is like a mob family. Annas is the "Don Emeretus" and always behind the scenes as the patriarch, but someone else in his family line is in charge on paper.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Both Annas and Caiaphas are called "high priest" because they both held the office, but not at the same time.  Annas held the office first and, later, his son-in-law Caiaphas came to throne. Annas also had several natural sons who became high priest. Many of the names and reigns of the high priests were preserved by Josephus. In the following list Annas is called "Ananus" and Caiaphas' given name is Joseph.
64. Ananus, son of Seth 
65. Ismael, son of Phabi 
66. Eleazar, son of Ananus 
67. Simon, son of Camithus 
68. Joseph (called "Caiaphas") 

In the gospels, when Annas is called "high priest" we should think of him as "former high priest." The title was honorific, but the narratives describe him as acting with authority even when his son-in-law was not present. In that respect he was senior, but is behavior in trying Jesus is thought by some to have been extra-legal in a number of ways. The Jewish Encyclopedia opines:

Though Caiaphas was the properly appointed high priest, Annas, being
his father-in-law and a former incumbent of the office, undoubtedly
exercised a great deal of the power attached to the position.

Conclusion: there was only one high priest at time. Annas and Caiaphas both held the office but not simultaneously.
